# Is possible migrate .NET Core (.NET 6) to .Net Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, migration, .net-framework-version, .net-4.8

I googled...

I only saw way to migrate ... **.Net Framework to .Net Core** , but no on the contrary(**.Net core to .Net Framework**)?

If have take .Net Core project and need migrate to .Net Framework? (is there any way?) ...  just curiosity.

Possibility of a practical solution or a tool that did this

Comment: The reason people are migrating from framework to core is framework is being phased out. You can install Core anywhere you are currently using Framework.

Answer (score 1):

I have not undertaken such a move manually but .NET Framework is at its end. All future .NET developments will proceed under .NET (Core)

.NET Framework 4.6.x and above will be frozen in long term support for about 10 years, getting critical updates for i.e. security but no newly developed features. [This breakdown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-framework) gives concrete dates for .NET Framework's lifecycles. To be honest, I am also unsure how long the support for various nuget packages for Framework will be kept up. Just because 4.6+ will be around for long, doesn't mean each and every 3rd party library will be getting updates. These are individuals and companies that most likely will be allocating their resources to cutting edge developments for .NET, not for .NET Framework

.NET Framework by definition is Windows only, while .NET is cross platform. You *should* be using .NET from now on

Also, take from me personally, I am stuck on .NET Framework 4.6 at my job and there are a lot of really cool things that are being added to the language that I wish I could use. Don't constrain yourself to .NET Framework if don't have to